# what are trailets in jupyter notebook ecosystem?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

while reading jupyter notebook documentation, I found this [picture](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/repos_map.svg)(svg) that demonstrates the interaction between it the component of the system.
At the very bottom, there is trailets which I didn't find anything about.

Can any one explain it's specific role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it may be just typo in documentation. It may be a python traitlets [github](https://github.com/ipython/traitlets) and [here a documentation](https://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)